# Node.js dependencies incompatibility on Linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, reactjs, ubuntu

Consistently getting this error when I call "sudo npm install":

```
Peer react-dom@0.14.9 wants react@^0.14.9
```

Prior to this, I called `sudo npm install react@0.14.9` and it installed without an issue.

I'm not sure why the `React` still flags this issue.

Comment: you also need to add -S (--save) flag to rewrite package.json

Comment: I did add the -S flag, but it still throws the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have `react-dom` under `dependencies` in your `package.json` but not the `react` package. When you do `npm install`, `react-dom` is being installed and by reading the `dependencies`, it realizes that you didn't include `react` in it and hence the warning.

Add `react` to your `package.json` manually or `npm install react@0.14.9 --save`.

Comment: I did that , but when i called "sudo npm install" afterwards, i was faced with a few incompatibilities, but the most constrained one being:

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@0.14.9 wants react@^0.14.9 ]

Comment: What's the react version installed in your package.json? It has to match react-dom's

Comment: I went to node_modules/react/package.json and the version here is 0.13.3

Comment: Yeah so that's the problem. Go to your project's root `package.json`, change the version to 0.14.9 and do `npm install` again.